# SQL error when I try to ALTER TABLE in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure designed to generate a new, 'derived' table. In this procedure I then want to add a column using ALTER TABLE. However, despite an almost identical stored procedure working fine, and despite being able to add this manually as a stored procedure to the database using MySQL Workbench, when I pass the code to the server using SOURCE (i.e. SOURCE workload.sql), I get an error 1146 (42502) 'Table 'workload._convenor_workload' doesn't exist.' (I'm doing this in Emacs as part of a org-babel block, but this is essentially just passing raw SQL to the server.)

As background, I'm in the process of migrating SQL code from a setting where I was running it raw to create my final database to one where I'd like this code to be called via triggers.

Setup: mysql  Ver 8.0.16 for macos10.14 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

I've tried rewriting this as a prepared statement, was unsuccessful, and have been scouring Stack Overflow. This is my first MySQL project and my reading of the documentation suggests that ALTER TABLE is a perfectly legal thing to do in a stored procedure. It's likely that I'm making a schoolboy error somewhere but at the moment I'm banging my head.

Elsewhere in my SQL, this code works in a stored procedure (ALTER TABLE function does not throw an error):

```
CREATE TABLE _assessment_allocations AS SELECT Assessment_ID,
   IFNULL(SUM(_total_first_marking_hours),0) AS _total_first_marking_hours_sum,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT _total_first_marking_hours_needed) AS _total_first_marking_hours_needed,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Prog_ID) AS prog_id
   FROM
   _marking_workload
GROUP BY Prog_ID, Assessment_ID;

ALTER TABLE _assessment_allocations
ADD COLUMN _assessment_variance DECIMAL(5,2);
```

However, the code that throws the error is this (specifically, the ALTER TABLE function; I've added the stored procedure code in case this is helpful). Note that this code does not throw an error when ingested by MySQL outside a stored procedure:

```
USE `workload`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `module_administration_convenor`()

-- Begin by selecting elements of the ~modules~ table
CREATE TABLE `_convenor_workload` AS
SELECT Modules.Module_Code,
       Modules.Module_Name,
       Modules.Module_Convenor_ID,
       Modules.Module_Convenor_Share,
       Modules.Student_Tally,
       Modules.Additional_Hours,
       Modules.Convening_Notes,
       Modules.Active_Status
FROM modules;

-- Add a 'Convenor' column
ALTER TABLE `_convenor_workload` ADD COLUMN `Name` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'Convenor';

\* Other stuff *\

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My aim is to avoid throwing this error. I'd like to get this stored procedure actually stored! (Just like the previous stored procedure that does much the same and does not throw an error.) I'm aware that there are some back-tick and style differences between the working and non-working code, but I'm guessing these aren't super important.

As I said, I have a strong suspicion that I'm overlooking something obvious here...

Comment: I am not sure if this is due to copy&paste, but there is a `begin` missing for the procedure.

Comment: Face, meet palm. Palm, this is face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Solarflare in the comments, you are missing a begin so the alter table is executing as a separate action. If you wrap it with begin and end then it treats all the code as the stored procedure.

```
USE `workload`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `module_administration_convenor`()
Begin
-- Begin by selecting elements of the ~modules~ table
CREATE TABLE `_convenor_workload` AS
SELECT Modules.Module_Code,
       Modules.Module_Name,
       Modules.Module_Convenor_ID,
       Modules.Module_Convenor_Share,
       Modules.Student_Tally,
       Modules.Additional_Hours,
       Modules.Convening_Notes,
       Modules.Active_Status
FROM modules;

-- Add a 'Convenor' column
ALTER TABLE `_convenor_workload` ADD COLUMN `Name` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'Convenor';
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks, Osher. Not seeing the wood for the trees on this one. The lesson here is that the error line SQL was giving me was, despite my intuition, very close to the problem (i.e. the start of the stored procedure).

Comment: I find it quite hard sometimes to link the error in MySQL to the actual problem in the code.